# Hiding the Console window instead of closing it

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I'm working on a program which uses a Console window and a WinForms Form. The user is supposed to write some commands in a textbox which is included in the Form and receive the results in the Console. Everything works fine, but there is an issue.

When the user attempts to close the program, it should only happen when the user uses the 'X' button on the Form, not the Console The same thing should happen when the user right clicks on the Titlebar and chooses the 'Close' option. The same thing should happen when the user attempts to close the Console when typing Alt + F4. When the user tries to close the Console window, my program should simply hide the Console window, not close completely my program.

I already have some code for hiding (and making visible again) my Console window, but I'm not sure as to how I can achieve what I want. Below is the code that I have so far for hiding/showing my console window:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

const int SW_HIDE = 0;
const int SW_SHOW = 5;

var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);
ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW);
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?